# Solution upgrade from VS2008 to VS2010 using boost library. Error LNK2001

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, boost, lnk2001, autolink

I'm currently attempting to build a solution developed in VS2008 in VS2010. For the design purpose the projects must be built using the v90 toolset and have a target framework of v3.5. After the conversion wizard was done with the imported projects I've gone through and changed each of their target frameworks/toolsets to these values. The projects use the following boost libraries: thread,system,regex and date_time. I have built these libraries from the boost_1_47 version to the v90 toolset using the following command in the VS2010 command prompt: *b2 toolset=msvc-9.0 –build-type=complete –with-'libraryname'.*

The links to the boost root folder is referenced in the C++ additional include directories and the boost lib folder the libraries were built into is referenced in the linker additional library directories. I am building for a 32 bit platform.

When attempting a build of the solution I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall boost::thread::operator struct boost::detail::thread_move_t<class boost::thread>(void)" (__imp_??Bthread@boost@@QAE?AU?$thread_move_t@Vthread@boost@@@detail@1@XZ)

Error   18  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class boost::thread & __thiscall boost::thread::operator=(struct boost::detail::thread_move_t<class boost::thread>)" (__imp_??4thread@boost@@QAEAAV01@U?$thread_move_t@Vthread@boost@@@detail@1@@Z)

Error   19  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I believe the cause of the error can be seen in the following part of the boost auto_link.hpp file:

```
#elif defined(BOOST_MSVC) && (BOOST_MSVC == 1500)

   // vc90:
#  define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc90"
#elif defined(BOOST_MSVC) && (BOOST_MSVC >= 1600)


// vc10:

#  define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc100"
```

This shows the auto linker is still attempting to link to a v100 library despite the boost library and the project files being set to a v90 toolset.  I don't know where/how the BOOST_MSVC value is defined but hopefully this is what's causing my linker errors.

My project build.h file contains the following statement:

`#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`